# navigation bar and sidebar in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

in ios app i want to implement "navigation-bar" and "side-bar" both in a single app like below image

[image]

for the tabbar controller i have to assign as a rootviewcontroller

and for sidebar controller also have to assign as a rootviewcontroller.

```
[self.window addSubview:[tabBarController view]];
```

and

```
 MenuViewController *menuViewController = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = menuViewController;
```

how two different tab-bar assigned as rootviewcontroller, any idea.. thanks in advance

Comment: what u want explin in sort

Comment: plz chk the image, https://www.dropbox.com/s/ucebn9ejrp5ntd0/Untitled.png

Comment: vertically display is UIView

Comment: ooo , but how to assign in appdelegate? both code asking to assign in rootviewcontroller

Comment: there in appdelegate.m u can see the code self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController; for the footer navigation i have also rootviewcontroller. 2 rootview controller will not work together. that is my question, how to made it

Comment: use this https://github.com/pkluz/ZUUIRevealController